# stochastic tree traversal in Clojure

Tags: algorithm, clojure

Given a tree encoded as a set of nested lists (e.g.,`(+ 2 (+ 2 1) (+ 1 3 2))`), is there a known algorithm in Clojure that stochastically traverses the tree, applying a parametrically supplied function at a single node, with equal probability of 'landing' at any node? Note: the walk terminates after a single node is transformed.

I expect the algorithm to behave as follows:

```
(def tree '(1 (1 (1 1 1) 1) 1))
(stochastic-tree-f-app inc tree) => (1 (1 (1 2 1) 1) 1)
(stochastic-tree-f-app inc tree) => (1 (1 (1 1 2) 1) 1)
(stochastic-tree-f-app inc tree) => (2 (1 (1 1 1) 1) 1)
(stochastic-tree-f-app inc tree) => (1 (1 (1 1 1) 1) 2)
(stochastic-tree-f-app dec tree) => (1 (1 (1 1 1) 0) 1)
```

Comment: So once you transformed one node, the walk is over, is that correct?

Comment: @ClojureMostly, yes, that is correct

Comment: A solution that comes to mind: 1. traverse the tree by bfs or dfs, returning the number of nodes 2. feed that number to a random integer generator, feeding the result (between 0 and n) to 3. a third d/bfs that traverses the graph the number of times specified by the random number generator 4. apply f

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a single node. Is it a form like `(+ 2 1)` ?  or only a value like `2`  ?   Do we need to exclude operators like `+` ?

Comment: Great question. We do not exclude operators like +. That is, we're not limited to values like `2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [clojure.zip](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.zip/zipper):

```
(require '[clojure.zip :as z])

(defn stochastic-tree-f-app [f tree]
  (let [zp    (z/zipper list? seq (fn [_ c] c) tree)
        nodes (->> (iterate z/next zp)
                   (take-while (complement z/end?))
                   (filter (comp integer? z/node))
                   (into []))]
    (-> (rand-nth nodes)
        (z/edit f)
        z/root)))
```

Comment: this is more beautiful

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use clojure.walk if the last requirement can be lifted (i.e. ...walk terminates after a single node is transformed).  Or walk down the nodes with a zipper and terminates with an edit.  Using clojure.walk:

```
(use 'clojure.walk)

(def tree '(1 (1 (1 1 1) 1) 1))

(defn stochastic-tree-f-app [f tree]
  (let [cnt (atom 0)
        _   (postwalk #(if (integer? %) (swap! cnt inc)) tree)
        idx (rand-int @cnt)]
    (reset! cnt 0)
    (postwalk #(if (and (integer? %) (= idx (swap! cnt inc)))
                (f %)
                %)
              tree)))

user> (stochastic-tree-f-app inc tree)
(2 (1 (1 1 1) 1) 1)
user> (stochastic-tree-f-app inc tree)
(1 (1 (1 1 1) 2) 1)
```

Comment: this is beautiful